# Binding a Dictionary(Of Integer, String) to the DataTextField property of a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, collections

I have a State class defined like this:

```
Public Class State
    Public Property StateId As Integer
    Public Property Name As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
End Class
```

Name(x) contains the state name in different languages.

I get a collection of State from the method StateManager.GetAllStates() 
and I want to bind this collection to a DropDownList. The problem is that 
I can't find how to set the DataTextField property to let's say stateList.Name(1) 
which is the english name of my state.

```
Dim stateList As StateCollection = StateManager.GetAllStates() 

Me.DataSource = stateList
Me.DataValueField = "StateId"
Me.DataTextField = "Name(1).Value" <-- Problem here
Me.DataBind()
```

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a data source, you can't use complex expressions to specify values.

Create a source where you extact the values that you need:

```
Me.DataSource = stateList.Select( _
  Function(s as State) New With { .Id = s.StateId, .Name = s.Name(1) } _
);
Me.DataValueField = "Id"
Me.DataTextField = "Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "Name(1).Value", have you tried:

```
Me.DataTextField = name(1).ToString
```

Comment: Same problem, DataBinding: 'State' does not contain a property with the name 'Name(1)'.

Comment: Maybe cast the property as a local Dictionary variable, and then pull it? Dim myNameDictionary = State.Name Me.DataTextField = myNameDictionary (1).ToString

Comment: Note that the DataTextField is a string naming the property to use from the data source, not the value itself.

Comment: @Guffa: nice catch, sorry about that!